# How do I handle a very old unanswered question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question a long time ago here on Android Enthusiasts. The question received only one answer back then but unfortunately it did not solve my problem. But now, the question seems to attract more answers to it and I don't even have a way of verifying any of these answers because I have already dumped that phone and I moved on.

What do I do if someone actually comes up with a good solution?

Now to avoid any kind of Meta Effect I am not going to post the link to the question.

Comment: What is a "Meta Effect"? Anyhow, irrespective of your wish not to post the question, I would definitely link it since I don't see a good reason not to post it: [How to add secondary patition on sd card to internal memory?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75443)

Comment: I knew you'd find it anyway! It's the only question I posted for crying out loud! :D

Comment: Yeah, right. But what is Meta Effect?

Comment: I guess you'd be more familiar with it you you were on StackOverflow. The thing is, there are people who bring up posts into meta just to get some rep out of it.

Comment: @Firelord [What is Meta Effect?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). Basically, by bringing a specific post on meta, it will attract community response (whether up/downvoted, flag/close, etc).

Comment: There aren't many members who read Meta Android.SE here, the meta effect is negligible btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange is very community-focused, so don't worry that you can't personally verify an answer.  Other users will vote/comment as they see fit and any useful information should float to the top.

If the question itself is localized to a particular situation that others won't encounter, or to software that is no longer available, etc. then the question should probably be closed.  You could flag it with a custom reason (explaining this) if that is the case.

In the case of the specific question Firelord linked, the new answers don't seem very good so I have protected the question; however, it does seem like it will be relevant to future users so I'm not going to close it.

Comment: Sounds fair enough :)